# kate filter unwanted files

Tags: kate

I like `kate` simple way to create a project from any folder - just need to create a file name `.kateproject` with the content something like this:

`{"name": "project-name", "files": [ { "directory": ".",  "recursive": 1 } ]}`

This works ok most of the time, except for one complain that after `make` there would be a bunch of object files (*.o) that I don't want to show up in the `Projects` plug-in view.

Anyone knows how to filter out these non-code files from the `Projects` view? Thanks.